# how to skip few element validations in xsd in java

Tags: java, xsd

I am trying to validate an xml against an xsd in java.
In XSD one of the field(tax_id) is defined as manadatory element.
But in my scenario I pass an xml to another component, that component fills the manadatory 
field(tax_id). 
Before sending that xml to the next component, I have to validate that xml against the xsd.
As, in that XSD element tax_id is defined as mandatory element, I get exception for not filling mandatory element (tax_id).
I can create a new xsd by making tax_id as optional field, but with this we would be having 2 xsds.

Is there any way to skip/ignore few elements while validating in java?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  The purpose of the XSD is to specify the rules that the document must meet, in order to be valid.  You can't ignore or skip some of those rules.   If you could, you'd probably have other problems.  For example, if required elements were really optional (or could be) then technically any element that was supposed to contain a bunch of other elements could be empty (and still valid) under that more lax validation.

In your situation, you probably have two options:

1. Change your workflow - make sure the first component populates the XML with the empty `tax_id`.  Then it will validate.
2. Introduce a second schema - one earlier in the "pipeline" of processing, that doesn't require `tax_id`.  Then validate against that.